# join 3 tables into 1 with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a main table to which I want to add 2 columns that are the sum of values from 2 other tables.

Tab1
Cod
Qty

Tab2
Cod
Qty

Tab3
Cod
Qty

I was able to write this code, which works for the first 2 tables,
but I would also like to add the Tab3 column, which should be:
Orders2=g.Sum(y=> y.Qty3),
but after multiple attempts I just can't join the third table.
Could you please explain how to do this?

```cs
var query =  
    from a in Tab1 
    join b in Tab2 
    on c.Cod equals b.Cod into temp 

    from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    group t by new {a.Cod, a.Qty1} into g 

    select new 
    { 
        g.Key.Cod, 
        g.Key.Qty1, 
        Orders = g.Sum(x => x.Qty2) 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it.

```
var query =  
    from a in Tab1 
    join b in Tab2 on a.Cod equals b.Cod into tempB
    join c in Tab3 on a.Cod equals c.Cod into tempC

    from tB in tempB.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from tC in tempC.DefaultIfEmpty()

    group new { tB, tC } by new { a.Cod, a.Qty1 } into g

    select new 
    { 
        g.Key.Cod, 
        g.Key.Qty1, 
        Orders = g.Sum(x => x.tB?.Qty2 ?? 0),
        Orders2 = g.Sum(x => x.tC?.Qty3 ?? 0)
    };
```

Comment: Keep `from tB in ` closer to `join b` - As I know, EF Core will not translate query in other case.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved it myself

I thought about creating another query that would call the first one so I could add another column summed.

Thanks anyway

```
var query1 =  
    from a in Tab1 
    join b in Tab2 on a.Cod equals b.Cod into tempB

    from tB in tempB.DefaultIfEmpty()

    group new { tB } by new { a.Cod, a.Qty1 } into g

    select new 
      { 
      cod = g.Key.Cod, 
      qty1 = g.Key.Qty1, 
      qty2 = g.Sum(x => x.tB.Qty2)
      };


var queryOK =  
    from c in query1 
    join d in Tab3 on c.cod equals d.Cod into tempC

    from tC in tempC.DefaultIfEmpty()

    group new { tC } by new { c.cod, c.qty1, c.qty2 } into k

    select new 
        { 
        cod = k.Key.cod, 
        qty1 = k.Key.qty1, 
        qty2 = k.Key.qty2,
        qty3 = k.Sum(y => y.tC.Qty3)
        };
    
dataGridView1.DataSource = query2.ToList();
```